# Mac Address for Estimote Beacon Android

Tags: android, mac-address, ibeacon-android, beacon, estimote

I'm retrieving the MAC address of a beacon both during the ranging and scanning parts.

For Ranging  - BeaconManager.setRangingListener - which returns beacon.getMacAddress

For Scanning - devicesScanner.scanForDevices - which returns device.macAddress where device is of type ConfigurableDevice

The problem that I'm facing is the both the methods return different MAC addresses for the same Estimote Beacon. Can anyone help me with what am I missing here ? How can a device have two different MAC addresses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching everywhere for this issue, I finally found the answer on Estimote forums.

ConfigurableDevicesScanner gives you the MAC address of the Connectivity packet and not the actual Beacon Mac Address. The MAC address is different coressponding to different broadcast packets.